# Error (Xcode): Unexpected duplicate tasks: Target 'Runner' has copy command from 'path/GoogleService-Info.plist' to 'path/GoogleService-Info.plist

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to run the flutter project on iOS after doing its setup with firebase properly but I am getting the following duplicate errors related to GoogleService-Info.plist.

here is the full error OutPut

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[24052]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b620) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b08598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[24052]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b670) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b085e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[24052]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b6c0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b08638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[24052]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b710) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b08688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[24052]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b760) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b086d8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[24052]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215b9b7b0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106b08728). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

here is xcode output

```
 Xcode's output:
    ↳
        Writing result bundle at path:
            /var/folders/8r/j5l1hdxj23n759qd_g_kkfk40000gn/T/flutter_tools.ApPpcn/flutter_ios_build_temp_diriZfLbr/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    
        note: Using new build system
        note: Planning
        note: Build preparation complete
        note: Building targets in parallel
        error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
        1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
        2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    
        Result bundle written to path:
            /var/folders/8r/j5l1hdxj23n759qd_g_kkfk40000gn/T/flutter_tools.ApPpcn/flutter_ios_build_temp_diriZfLbr/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    
    
    Error (Xcode): Unexpected duplicate tasks:
    1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    
    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

kindly help me to resolve this

```
Error (Xcode): Unexpected duplicate tasks:
1) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
2) Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/rashidali/Flutter_projects/lubanpoint/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Xcode, under the Build Phases of your target, ensure that the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file *is* included in the **Copy Bundle Resources** phase, but *is not* included in the **Compile Sources** phase. I had it in both and after removing it from Compile Sources the error was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

IMPORTANT: ensure doing all the below steps using xCode. DON'T use any other IDE or other file explorer. It has to be xCode. xCode does something under the hood when you drag and drop a file to your project which is why you would not use any other IDE to do this.

first: remove all `GoogleService-Info.plist` from your project.

second: drag and drop a fresh copy of `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the 'project runner' path

third: try running your project again and it should be working fine.

Comment: The above answer worked for me. I recently renamed the package structure application and after running `firebase configure` command, all of a sudden I started getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you @ranjjose. I am happy that it did help you. A question though, why did you need to rename your app package?

Comment: Oh! we had a text `example` in the package structure :-) Had to change it before the app is released. The `firebase configure` updated the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and as you said, whatever Xcode is adding under the hood when you manually drag the file, isn't happening when the file gets updated by other means it seems!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, xcode had a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file under Runner and also referencing another file (not visible in directory) Hence the error. Here's what I did to resolve it

1. Under Targets Runner -> Build phases
2. Expand `Compile Sources` and `Copy Bundle Resources` and ensure you don't have a same file in both. If you see a duplicate drop the file from Copy Bundle Resources

Ref: https://github.com/Swiftify-Corp/IHProgressHUD/issues/9#issuecomment-882116029