# Multiple commands produce (Xcode) ERROR. Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation)

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

everything was perfectly fine error just occurred suddenly and the app is running on an android emulator without giving any ERROR.
**full error message:**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (3rd generation) in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           15.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-09-17 15:47:53.105 xcodebuild[33256:287345] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-09-17 15:47:53.105 xcodebuild[33256:287345] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/w6/8yc1cn8x557482n7l7f_mvp80000gn/T/flutter_tools.TSMnLr/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRdX4nE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
        note: Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
        note: Target 'Runner' (project 'Runner') has copy command from '/Users/eapple/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist' to '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist' on task: CopyPlistFile /Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist /Users/eapple/Downloads/GoogleService-Info.plist (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/w6/8yc1cn8x557482n7l7f_mvp80000gn/T/flutter_tools.TSMnLr/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirRdX4nE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce '/Users/eapple/Documents/flutterProjects/whatsapp_clone/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/GoogleService-Info.plist'

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone SE (3rd generation).
Exited
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73653470/error-xcode-unexpected-duplicate-tasks-target-runner-has-copy-command-from/73658372#73658372) may help.